# Are Machine Learning Studios's web services public?

Tags: azure, web-services, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I have created an experiment in Machine Learning Studio and deployed it as a web service. I've got a request-response API in my workspace that works. Can it be also used by other people?

Comment: Can you please add more details about the deployment settings that you have configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you deploy a model, a Webservice object is returned with information about the service.

```
from azureml.core.webservice import AciWebservice, Webservice
from azureml.core.model import Model

deployment_config = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores = 3, memory_gb = 15, location = "centralus")
service = Model.deploy(ws, "aciservice", [model], inference_config, deployment_config)
service.wait_for_deployment(show_output = True)
print(service.state)
```

[image]
Please follow the below to Consume an Azure Machine Learning model deployed as a web service
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-consume-web-service